# How to combine two data frame in PySpark aws Glue

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have two `dataframes` which get records from database using aws glue and both database has same columns .
I am getting count for the id for `dataframe` one and same for `dataframe` two .
Now i am printing this two `dataframe` separately which make difficult to read like report .

So in order to do so i want to combine these two `dataframe` into one line .like one row .

For example we have a `dataframe` result

Data Frame One Output

```
id,"count(1)"
"02adba80-0b00-4094-8645-wrwer",2527
"0a34803c-64eb-12fd-9940-www",35008
"0a34805f-669c-167f-99a7-44",8
"0a370f68-6c05-1aa6-9b12-55",5
"0a370f69-6c05-1aa0-9b0e-66",8
"0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff6-9b06-77",13
```

Data Frame Two Output

```
id,"count(1)"
"02adba80-0b00-4094-8645-wrwer",2527
"0a34803c-64eb-12fd-9940-www",35008
"0a34805f-669c-167f-99a7-44",9
"0a370f68-6c05-1aa6-9b12-55",5
"0a370f69-6c05-1aa0-9b0e-66",9
"0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff6-9b06-77",10
```

Now for reporting and beeter readability puspose i want this be save like belwo

```
idaws,"count(1)aws"                             idonprem,"count(1)onprem"
"02adba80-0b00-4094-8645-wrwer",2527           "02adba80-0b00-4094-8645-wrwer",2527
"0a34803c-64eb-12fd-9940-www",35008            "0a34803c-64eb-12fd-9940-www",35008
"0a34805f-669c-167f-99a7-44",8                 "0a34805f-669c-167f-99a7-44",9
"0a370f68-6c05-1aa6-9b12-55",5                 "0a370f68-6c05-1aa6-9b12-55",5
"0a370f69-6c05-1aa0-9b0e-66",8                 "0a370f69-6c05-1aa0-9b0e-66",9
"0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff6-9b06-77",13                "0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff6-9b06-77",10
```

to this i used union but it does not gives result as expected it adds up in different rows not in same column
Please suggest how can we do

here is my pyspark

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.transforms import Join
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


##Loading Data Source one Mysql
customer_case= glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "a204795-laskhya-report", table_name = "fsp_customer_case", transformation_ctx = "customer_case")
customer_case.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("customer_case")

##Loading Data Source two Mysql 
groupdf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "a204795-laskhya-report", table_name = "fsp_fsp_group", transformation_ctx = "group")
groupdf.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("groupdf")

##Combning Data Source one and two from AWS side  

resultdfMysql=spark.sql("select  p.id, count(1) from customer_case cc join groupdf c on cc.owner_id = c.id join groupdf p on p.id = substr(c.path, 2, instr(substr(c.path, 2), '/') - 1) where  p.status='ACTIVE' and c.status='ACTIVE' group by p.id")
OuptutdfMysql=DynamicFrame.fromDF(resultdfMysql, glueContext, "mydfSource")


                               ###Source Connection On prem side##################
##Loading Data Source one Orcale On prem
customer_caseSourcedf= glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "a204795-source-qa1", table_name = "_ort487a_int_thomsonreuters_com__fsp_customer_case", transformation_ctx = "customer_case")
customer_caseSourcedf.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("customer_caseSourcedf")

##Loading Data Source two  Orcale On prem
groupSourcedf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "a204795-source-qa1", table_name = "_ort487a_int_thomsonreuters_com__fsp_fsp_group", transformation_ctx = "group")
groupSourcedf.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("groupSourcedf")


##Combning Data Source one and two from ON prem side 
resultdfOracle=spark.sql("select  p.id, count(1) from customer_caseSourcedf cc join groupSourcedf c on cc.owner_id = c.id join groupSourcedf p on p.id = substr(c.path, 2, instr(substr(c.path, 2), '/') - 1) where  p.status='ACTIVE' and c.status='ACTIVE' group by p.id")
OuptutdfOracle=DynamicFrame.fromDF(resultdfOracle, glueContext, "mydfOracle")


##Finaly we need to combine Data Frame one and Two here 
resultSourcedfFinal = OuptutdfMysql.join(OuptutdfOracle, 'id', 'left')


##OuptutSourcedf=DynamicFrame.fromDF(resultSourcedfFinal, glueContext, "mydf")
repartitionedSource1 = resultSourcedfFinal.repartition(1)
datasinkSource2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = repartitionedSource1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://a204795-aryabhata/AGLUE/OEACLE", "compression": "gzip"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

Above code does not give me desired result
and gets error like

```
IllegalArgumentException: "requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (2): id, count(1)\nNew column names (0): "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a left_join as below assuming the keys are unique as per the example:

**df_a.show()**

```
+--------------------+-----+
|                  ID|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|02adba80-0b00-409...| 2527|
|0a34803c-64eb-12f...|35008|
|0a34805f-669c-167...|    9|
|0a370f68-6c05-1aa...|    5|
|0a370f69-6c05-1aa...|    9|
|0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff...|   10|
+--------------------+-----+
```

**df_b.show()**

```
+--------------------+-----+
|                  ID|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|02adba80-0b00-409...| 2527|
|0a34803c-64eb-12f...|35008|
|0a34805f-669c-167...|    8|
|0a370f68-6c05-1aa...|    5|
|0a370f69-6c05-1aa...|    8|
|0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff...|   13|
+--------------------+-----+

df_b = df_b.join(df_a, 'id', 'left')
df_b.show()
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|                  ID|count|count|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
|0a34803c-64eb-12f...|35008|35008|
|0a34805f-669c-167...|    8|    9|
|0a370f6c-6c0d-1ff...|   13|   10|
|0a370f69-6c05-1aa...|    8|    9|
|02adba80-0b00-409...| 2527| 2527|
|0a370f68-6c05-1aa...|    5|    5|
+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: I am still not able to save data frame into above format ypdated my question on how i am saving my data frame into s3 and can we rename count as awscount and onpremcount

Comment: Please use withColumnRenamed : df = df.withColumnRenamed('old_column_name','new_column_name)

Comment: when i save it i am able to see only one Frame result one count only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_aws = df_aws.withColumnRenamed('count','aws_count')
df_onprem = df_onprem.withColumnRenamed('count','onprem_count')
df = df_aws.join(df_onprem, 'id', 'left')
df.repartition(1).write.csv("s3://a204795-bucket/AGLUE/OEACLE")
job.commit()
```

Comment: Left join is no working here i feel its Python spark and Glue may be because of that ?